# Send character not working in mailutils

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I'm trying to send an email from the console:

```
louis@ubuntu:~$ mail user@example.com
Cc:
Subject: Testing Postfix
This is the full body.
.
.
.


.
.
.
```

You can see I'm unable to get out of the body. The man page mainly dealt with the command line, but websearches say <kbd>.</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> should send the message.

I'm not sure what the problem could be, but I'll mention I'm a putty user on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`.` on a line by itself only terminates the message if the `dot` option in `mailx` is set on.  If it is set off, as it apparently is here (Check your `/etc/mail.rc` and `~/.mailrc`.), the you need to signal EOF on your terminal with your terminal's EOF special character (whatever it may be — See the output of `stty -a` to find out.) to end the message.